# How or why are powerful but low-frequency radio waves, such as from a radio station or cell tower, potentially dangerous?

Tags: rf, radio, microwave, cellphone, radiation

Cell towers / base stations and such are limited in the power they are allowed use, even if the wavelengths of radiation used do not adversely affect people or animals.

I have heard (and read) that it is not just a matter of different transmitters interfering with each others' signals, but that high wattage is potentially 'dangerous'.

How?

Comment: If you get very close to a very high power transmitter it can heat enough to cause burns (see microwave ovens).  Most of the time power is regulated to prevent interference rather than for safety since most radios are not powerful enough to appreciably heat living things.  Perhaps you had a specific example in mind where safety was a factor?

Comment: In general, when you concentrate enough of anything, energy or otherwise, it becomes hazardous. An effect can be harmless at reasonable levels but all effects become harmful when you simply have too much. It's not unlike visible light vs visible laser light, or patting you on the back vs a truck hitting you in the back. The damage caused by ionizing radiation UV, x-rays, or gamma rays cause damage on a much more targeted, less macro scale and so takes much less and is not simply a matter of just too much.

Comment: You may want to clarify what your source is, and what sort of distances they're talking about.  There is some fringe pseudo-science about perceived dangers to cell and radio towers that is not borne out when subjected to rigid statistical analysis.

Comment: Cell phones themselves are not above suspicion. You’re shoving a radio emitter right next to your head. The inverse square law doesn’t factor well in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

> Cell towers / base stations and such are limited in the power they are
> allowed use, even if the **wavelengths** of radiation used do not
> adversely affect people or animals.

All radio waves - even those with 'low' frequency - can adversely affect people or animals if the power is high enough, so they are *all* 'potentially' dangerous. The main danger is that the energy absorbed could raise body temperature enough to damage tissue or cause heatstroke symptoms.

But how much power is dangerous? A lot - far more than a person would normally be exposed to. Cell phone towers are limited mostly to prevent interference. Most have an [actual](https://www.fcc.gov/consumers/guides/human-exposure-radio-frequency-fields-guidelines-cellular-and-pcs-sites) radiated power of 5-10 watts. Since the radio wave expands with distance to cover a wider area according to the [inverse square law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law), once it reaches a person the exposure is negligible.

The *absorbed* power is even less because the body is not a perfect antenna. The resonant frequency of the human body is [between 30 and 100 Mhz](https://www.emf-portal.org/en/cms/page/home/effects/radio-frequency). At higher frequencies the waves penetrate the body less and so can cause more localized heating, but at normal distances they are spread over the whole body so the power density at any spot is still low.

[image]

Unlike cell phone towers, broadcast radio and TV stations don't have to receive weak signals from low powered handheld units, so they can be much more powerful. A high power TV transmitter might output 10 kW at 100 MHz, while an AM broadcast transmitter might produce 500 kW at 1 MHz. That is definitely enough power to be dangerous. However again the inverse square law turns this into milliwatts at the closest distance you can normally get to the transmitter.

Where radio waves could be dangerous is when getting 'up close and personal' with a transmitter. Even low power can be harmful if it is concentrated enough. So don't go climbing up a transmitter tower and positioning yourself in front of the antenna, or looking down any active waveguides, if you want to stay healthy.